# iOS Custom Font Special Characters Wrong On UILabel

Tags: ios, fonts, uilabel

I purchased a the font LemonYellowSun. It has ö, ä, ü and ß characters.
[image: The Font]

The selected A in the Image got the dots but they are not selected and overlaps with the P. UILabels won't show the dots above as seen here.

[image: missing dots image]

Is there a way to tell UILabel to render above its normal rect to display the dots? Disable clip subviews isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by subclassing UILabel and overriding the `-intrinsicContentSize` function:

```
import UIKit

class BiggerLabel: UILabel {
    override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
        var normalSize = super.intrinsicContentSize()
        normalSize.height += 4
        return normalSize
    }
}
```